# Machine learning model test

Tags: bazel

I have a Java unit test which will use a machine learning model file, call it `model.bin`, which is being built from a simple text file by an external tool (call it `model-builder`, already built through a C++ rule). While it would make sense to define a [`genrule`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule), it doesn't support `deps` (`model.bin` & `model-builder` in my case). I see two options:

- Make my test code build the `model.bin` file. Conceptually, this is not really what I want my test to test (I want to test reading the prebuild model).
- Implement a custom extension [rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html) that executes `./model-builder --in my-input.txt --out`model.bin`.

What is best-practise in Bazel?

Answer (score 2):

From your description I believe a genrule is the best route. Even though genrule does have deps it sounds like `model.bin` is your generated file and would make sense as an `out`. `model-builder` looks like the tool to generate your file and would make sense as a genrule `tool`.

Something like this as a `BUILD` file should work.

```
genrule(
  name = "model-bin",
  srcs = ["//path/to:my-input.txt"],
  outs = ["model.bin"],
  tools = ["//path/to:model-builder"],
  cmd = "$(location //path/to:model-builder) --in $< --out $@"
)
```